# Does Hibernate support fetching data concurrently?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, concurrency

I understand this is a difficult question since it does not only depend on hibernate, but also the particular way we use it. 
We use hibernate 4 in our application, probably in a wrong way, but this is how it is.

So we load a whole class hierarchy, with joined subclass tables in one big statement and get in the order of 150K rows that we turn into objects.

Since the objects have lots of fields to set (~100), we would like to parallelize the loop that iterates over the result set and gets the individual rows. Is this possible in Hibernate? Is there a point at which Hibernate has received all the results from the DB and can use the data to hydrate objects, so we can use multithreading to speed up fetching a large result set?

Does this make sense or is it better to change the data structure and the mapping to get rid of multi-table joins?

As it is, loading 150K of those objects takes a minute or 0.3 ms/entity. We have simpler tables with more entries that we load one order of magnitude faster at 0.02 ms/entity. We do not load other entities after the initialization phase which takes more than 5 minutes for the whole DB.

If we remove joins by unexposing the class hierarchy to the DB and switch to a composition-based data structure, we may get more simple table loads instead of complex joins at the cost of multiple table loads instead one join that has those loads combined into one.

But the problem remains: if we have this many rows to load and accordingly many setters to call when filling out the fields for each object, can this be done in parallel?

Comment: Well parallel fetch strategy is a possibility, but IMHO you will add more complexity to the system. Also at this moment its hard to judge scalability  of such a solution. My advice will be (if you have time) to review the data objects and do away with unwanted joins and data.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such a thing in Hibernate.

However, if the data sets you mention are independent from each other, you could load each of the data sets you have in different sessions (transactions) in different threads concurrently (one thread and session per one data set). Then just take the results from all the threads.

The additional benefit of this approach is that you also parallelize query executions for the data sets.

Comment: The problem in JPA is that EntityManager was designed to be used only within a single thread. If you want to load data in parallel, you need to separated the work into different transactions with different entitymanagers. However, if you want to end up having all data in one entitymanager after all, you may attach loaded entities into one final EM using em.merge(). But this might execute much more SQL queries then fetching data in one thread, therefore making loading even slower.

Comment: True, but the question is then, do you really need such a huge amount of data in one Hibernate session? If yes, then preloading everything in L2 cache in multiple threads and then reading it with the final EM should produce much less amount of queries (in an ideal case `em.merge()` would read everything from the L2 cache). But even without merging, a query like `select * from SomeEntity` will execute much less additional queries if `SomeEntity`'s associations are in the second-level cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all entities into the second level cache, then indeed you might want to fetch all that data, but I think it's not really a good idea.

I think you should only cache the most accessed data, instead of the whole entries. This way the cache will require less space and you will not need to fetch the whole result set at once.

If you really want to fetch all that data, I would suggest another approach.

You can parallelize the fetch on multiple threads using Java concurrency, so you set up an EexcutorService that takes a Callable and tries to fetch at entries in batches.

If you have N processors you can use N worker threads for this. You divide the root entity ID interval by N, so you can obtain N sub intervals. Each working thread will process one such interval and load data in batches. This way you don;t have to synchronize the N working threads for avoiding loading the same data twice. Because the ID is usually indexed anyway, sorting the entries by the root entity ID and fetching batches starting from the last processed ID might speed up the loading significantly.